# Problem with GitHub pages using Remote Theme In GitHub Enterprise

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, github-enterprise, jekyll-theme

I have created a separate repo in our organization to store the custom documents and guidelines,
so Chosen GitHub-Pages to publish it. I'm very new to Jekyll, but somehow managed to learn and used a custom theme 'Just the docs' and published the pages. In my local machine it's working perfectly fine. when i push the changes to GHE, the website is broken, and theme is not applied over there.

Local Machine working image, theme applied
[image: Website working in local]
GitHub Pages Published, theme not applied
[image: Github Pages published image]

In my GHE setting, i kept correct branch and correct source.

_config.yml

```
remote_theme: just-the-docs/just-the-docs
logo: images\logo.png
title: Docs
email: <custom value>
description: >- # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll
footer_content: If you have any questions or concerns regarding the information in this repository, please contact us at 
# Build settings
plugins:
  - Jekyll-feed
```

I tried to publish the 'just -the-docs' theme to our own GHE and changed the GEM file path also , not worked.

Comment: Not super clear. Check the baseurl and use the inspector to see why CSS is not applied as expected. A leading slash can help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSS isn't getting loaded. GitHub pages does a weird thing with directories so you'll need to add a [relative URL filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) to where your CSS. I do this with all my jekyll sites. Here's an example snippet

```
<link href="{{ '/css/style.min.css' | relative_url }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In this example above I turn the CSS path into a liquid object then apply the relative_url filter so that path always points to the root site folder not necessarily the root domain. Github pages hosts sites on a path of your github domain, eg username.github.io/my-site so if you have a relative URL for your CSS it's pointing it to username.github.io/css/styles.min.css where it doesn't exist. The relative URL filter: `relative_url` solves this issue.

If you don't have access to the document head where the CSS is loaded then I would suggest using [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) to host your Jekyll site. They have a very generous free plan and no restrictions on plugins.